# Displaying several integers in one label

Tags: c#, sum, int, label

I need some clarification. I'm doing a lab project that wants me to gather 5 numbers, then when a button is clicked it adds them, divides them into dozens, and also tells the remainder. here's a portion of my code, I'm wanting to know if there's something I'm missing in the line with label2?

```
        int sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;
        int dozen = sum / 12;
        int remainder = sum % 12;

        label2.Text = "The total is {0}. That's {1} dozen with {2} remainders",sum , dozen, remainder;

    }
}
```

}

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, you're missing a call to `string.format` or nowadays you can do `label2.Text = $"The total is {sum}. That's {dozen} dozen with {remainder} remainders";`

Comment: Thanks!!! I've been stuck on this for two days! I tried to find answers before asking but I couldn't take it anymore. It worked perfectly!

Comment: you're welcome! ;-)

Comment: The magic of string interpolation only happens if you prepend a `$` to the string: `$"a = {a}, b = {b}"`

Comment: @Aominè please post comment as answer..otherwise this question keep popping up over and over again in the question-list. @ Aaron... when answer is posted select as best answer. This removes question from the list of unsolved riddles.

Comment: @ZF007 right, my bad. that's now done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
label2.Text = String.Format("The total is {0}. That's {1} dozen with {2} remainders",sum , dozen, remainder);
```

String.Format take arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're missing a call to `string.format` or nowadays you can do:

```
label2.Text = $"The total is {sum}. That's {dozen} dozen with {remainder} remainders";
```